# Free location-aware todo list

Tags: gps, freeware, productivity, to-do-list

Is there a free location-aware todo list out there?

I need something, that: reminds me to buy milk, when I'm near to my favourite shop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New app [Location Alert](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mofirst.locationalert) will do this.

> Never forget another task with
>   Location Alert - now available
>   completely free! Location Alert is a
>   cutting-edge application that reminds
>   you to perform tasks based upon your
>   current location, rather than time.
>   Often there are tasks to which you
>   cannot specify a certain time,
>   however, would like to be reminded
>   when in a certain vicinity. For
>   instance, you don’t know when exactly
>   you will leave work this evening, but
>   whenever you do, and are crossing the
>   grocery store on your way home, you
>   want to be reminded to pick up milk.
>   Location Alert to the rescue!
>
> - Don't know what time you'll be crossing the science department, but
>     need to remember to drop off that
>     assignment whenever you do?
> - Don't know what time you'll reach office but must remember to hand in
>     that check to accounting?
> - Need a reminder to pick up the DVD you left at Sam's house whenever
>     you're in the vicinity next time?
>
> ...

Answer (score 4):

If you are already using Locale (which is not free), Astrid is a free task/todo list manager which can be configured to open a list of tasks with a specific tag.  Astrid also integrates with Remember the Milk.

You can configure the list to open by various Locale conditions, including location.

I use it to remind me of maintenance tasks when I'm near the hardware store.

Additionally, Remember the Milk is a free app which can trigger by location, but it does require a Pro subscription to Remember The Milk's website.

Comment: The developers of Astrid wrote a blog post on our website about how to configure Astrid with Locale.  Please take a look here http://blog.twofortyfouram.com/post/1576204148/improve-productivity-with-locale-astrid

Comment: Unfortunately Astrid no more supports RTM :(

Answer (score 1):

[Google Keep](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.keep) now supports location reminders.